# Line Break for OSX

Tags: macos

A set of [(DOS) ANSI-C text files (click here to download)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6nbish0be1pvmha/raymond-floppydisk.zip?dl=0) was copied to a OSX High Sierra laptop.  I would like to ensure that the CR\LF is not an obstacle to to compiling the files. The files seem to be displayed correctly by Sublime and vi.

[The three terminators](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mac-os-x/0596004605/ch01s06.html) are:

1. The Mac, by default, uses a single carriage return (CR), represented as \r.
2. Unix, on the other hand, uses a single linefeed (LF), \n.
3. Windows goes one step further and uses both, creating a (CRLF) combination, \r\n.

`dos2unix` was installed:

```
brew install dos2unix
```

attempts to process the ANSI-C files returns [an errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29924397/4953146):

```
$ dos2unix *.h
dos2unix: Binary symbol 0x1A found at line 75
dos2unix: Skipping binary file error.h
dos2unix: Binary symbol 0x1A found at line 156
dos2unix: Skipping binary file random.h
dos2unix: Binary symbol 0x1A found at line 49
dos2unix: Skipping binary file resource.h
dos2unix: Binary symbol 0x1A found at line 107
dos2unix: Skipping binary file results.h
dos2unix: Binary symbol 0x1A found at line 261
dos2unix: Skipping binary file sim_lib.h
dos2unix: Binary symbol 0x1A found at line 27
dos2unix: Skipping binary file stats.h
```

.c files

```
$ dos2unix *.c
dos2unix: Binary symbol 0x1A found at line 110
dos2unix: Skipping binary file error.c
dos2unix: Binary symbol 0x1A found at line 780
dos2unix: Skipping binary file random.c
dos2unix: Binary symbol 0x1A found at line 79
dos2unix: Skipping binary file resource.c
dos2unix: Binary symbol 0x1A found at line 582
dos2unix: Skipping binary file results.c
dos2unix: Binary symbol 0x1A found at line 1755
dos2unix: Skipping binary file sim_lib.c
dos2unix: Binary symbol 0x1A found at line 102
dos2unix: Skipping binary file stats.c
```

## QUESTIONS

What are the steps required to ensure that the correct terminator is applied?

How can one visualize (verify) which terminator is engaged? (CR \ LF \ CRLF)

## Update

The -f (force) flag will ignore the 0x1A and process the file.  Recursively find .c files:

```
user@hostname:~/csim$ find . -name '*.c' | xargs dos2unix -f
```

Comment: Should you post an example of the relevant error lines (in hex with `od` for example)?

Comment: You may want to have a look at some or all of those files to figure out what role that `0x1a` character is playing in each of them. It seems unrelated to line termination.

Comment: Answers do not go in questions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple test :

```
~/tmp$ printf "\x1Aabc\r\n" > test
~/tmp$ od -a test
0000000  sub   a   b   c  cr  nl                                        
0000006
~/tmp$ dos2unix test
dos2unix: Binary symbol 0x1A found at line 1
dos2unix: Skipping binary file test
~/tmp$ dos2unix -f test
dos2unix: converting file test to Unix format...
~/tmp$ od -a test
0000000  sub   a   b   c  nl                                            
0000005
```

. Use `dos2unix -f` to force conversion

. Use `od -a` to view binary file

. Terminator on Mac is LF as well.

Comment: clever and innovative